# Coexistence of a static electric and magnetic dipole

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, magnetic-moment, dipole, dipole-moment

I have been trying to construct a charged object (not a conductor carrying any current) that can behave simultaneously as an electric and magnetic dipole and then calculate the electric and magnetic forces of interaction between two copies of this object at a large distance, and possibly associate an energy of interaction with this system as well (just the minimum energy required to assemble the system starting with all elements at infinity).

However, insofar, I have been quite unsuccessful. My first thought was to construct a ring with a charge distribution of $\lambda=\lambda_0 \cos(\theta)$ and make this ring rotate with a certain velocity $\omega$ to establish an "effective" current. While this behaves as an electric dipole, I calculated its magnetic dipole moment to be $M=\dfrac{\lambda_0 \omega R^3}{2}\int_0^{2\pi} \cos(\theta) \,d\theta =0$. Similar issues occur when I tried to consider a disc, spherical shell and solid sphere with a charge distribution dependent on the angle a ring-like element subtended at the center.

Next, I thought of considering a rotating rod with a linearly varying charge distribution from $-Q$ to $+Q$ at the other end (basically $\lambda (x)=-Q+\dfrac{2Q}{l} x)$, rotating about its one end but two issues arise herein; firstly, it is a rotating electric dipole and I have never dealt with such a scenario and I do not know how it may affect the force of interaction between two such rods. Secondly, I'm having a little trouble calculating the magnetic moment; considering an element $dx$ at a distance $x$ from the one end, it appears that $di_{eq}=dq/dt=\dfrac{\lambda(x) \omega dx}{2\pi}$ and hence since $A=\pi x^2$,
$$M=\int A.di=\dfrac{\omega}{2}\int_{0}^{l}x\lambda(x)dx=\dfrac{Q \omega l^2}{12}$$

But, this seems to break the well-known rule about the gyromagnetic ratio for a system with circular symmetry (where ring-like elements may be taken) stating that $\dfrac{M}{L}=\dfrac{Q}{2m}$ since it gives the ratio to be $\dfrac{Q}{4m}$ (Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gyromagnetic_ratio#For_a_classical_rotating_body)

where $L$ is the angular momentum. So, to summarize, I have 3 queries associated with this one problem;

1. Can there exist a system that can be modeled as a stationary electric and magnetic dipole (i.e. no dipole vector is translating or rotating) simultaneously? If so, can one give a concrete example of the same?
2. Why is the rotating rod violating the rule regarding the gyromagnetic ratio?
3. Does the rotation of the electric dipole vector in the rod scenario render the formula $F=\dfrac{6\mu_0 p_1p_2}{4\pi r^4}$ inapplicable? If so, why? What would be the modified formula for the electric force of interaction between to such identical rotating rods at a distance $r>>l$?

Comment: Why not have a bar with opposite charges on either pole, and a ring of current, sharing the same origin, but not intersecting?

Comment: You can write charge-current expressions with delta functions and their derivatives, and get pure electric and magnetic dipoles superimposed

Comment: Okay, just to clarify: horizontal bar and a rotating charged ring whose plane is perpendicular to the bar with its circumference touching the bar at one end?

Comment: Oh, I missed that you did not want to have explicit current prescribed. Fine, a pair of positively and negatively charged rings rotating in opposite directions, same axis of symmetry, same radius, separation between them controls electric dipole, speed of rotation and charge controls magnetic dipole

Comment: Why the limitation on prescribing current though? Makes life difficult. Does it help? You can still have interaction energy with currents

Comment: Oh, that's an idea I missed completely, I'll get to work on it right away; the reason I decided not to prescribe current is because I also want to possibly later figure out the torque/forces involved in keeping such a system running and the power delivered. I also don't know how current can be associated with the assembling energy so that's why.

Comment: Not sure you can avoid problems this way. I am guessing, but it looks to me like you may want to use Coulomb-type solutions to get the 'assembling energy'. Well, those are for fixed charges. You can sort of use them for inertial charges after some messing about with Lorentz boosts, but circular motion is non-inertial. So Coulomb-fields are not appropriate solutions of Maxwell's equations for spinning/rotating charge assemblies. I think you will need to find a way of using currents and charges. A good place to start here might be Hamiltonian in presence of charges and currents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to look at interaction energy, it is a good idea to start with a Hamiltonian for the system, i.e. something that would be conserved in time:

With some work you can show that if electromagnetic Lagrangian does not have explicit time dependence, and there is no dissipation ($\mathbf{E}.\mathbf{J}=0$) then the following quantity is conserved in time:

$$
H=\int_V d^3r\left[\frac{\epsilon_0}{2}E^2+\frac{1}{2\mu_0}B^2\right]
$$

Where $\mathbf{E}$ is the electric field $\mathbf{B}$ is the magnetic field, $\mathbf{J}$ is the current density, $\epsilon_0$ is the permittivity of the free space and $\mu_0$ is the permeability of the free space. This is your conserved energy. $V$ is the volume over which you integrate

If the current density $\mathbf{J}$ and charge density $\rho$ are constant in time, and therefore so are the scalar potential $\phi$ and the vector potential $\mathbf{A}$, we can re-write it in terms potentials:

$$
H=\frac{1}{2}\int_V d^3 r\left[\phi\rho+\mathbf{J}.\mathbf{A}\right]
$$

This is the expression you can use to evaluate all your expressions. For example a combination of electric dipole $\mathbf{p}$ and magnetic dipole $\mathbf{m}$ at point $\mathbf{r_1}$ has charge current configuration:

$$
\begin{align}
\rho&=\mathbf{p}.\boldsymbol{\nabla}\delta^{(3)}\left(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}_1\right)\\
\mathbf{J}&=\boldsymbol{\nabla}\times\mathbf{m}\delta^{(3)}\left(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}_1\right)
\end{align}
$$

You can evaluate the energy using the normal rules for the delta functions:

$$
H=\frac{1}{2}\left[-\mathbf{p}.\boldsymbol{\nabla}\phi_1+\mathbf{m}.\boldsymbol{\nabla}\times\mathbf{A}_1\right]
$$

Where $\boldsymbol{\nabla}\phi_1$ means evaluated at point $\mathbf{r}_1$. To look at the interaction energy between two dipole configurations at different points, you would find the potentials ($\phi$, $\mathbf{A}$) generated by the second configuration, at point $\mathbf{r}_2\neq\mathbf{r}_1$, and substitute into the above expression.

Comment: The negative gradient of this expression for interaction energy gives the net force of interaction automatically too. This is a better way of looking at it, thanks!